# Geolocation API is not working with Vue.js

Tags: javascript

I am trying to grab geolocation for my app. Geolocation should be grabbed on created hook.

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayLocationInfo);
}

function displayLocationInfo(position) {
  const lng = position.coords.longitude;
  const lat = position.coords.latitude;

  console.log(`longitude: ${ lng } | latitude: ${ lat }`);
}
```

But my console is empty.

Comment: my console prints `longitude: 90.3979008 | latitude: 23.765811199999998` after giving permission

Answer (score 1):

The real way to use **Geolocation** API is to check the availability of it on your device/browser before using it, so just add an `else` block to your existing code. Hope it'll help :) See more at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API)

```js
if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
  /* geolocation is available */
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayLocationInfo);
  
  function displayLocationInfo(position) {
    const lng = position.coords.longitude;
    const lat = position.coords.latitude;

    console.log(`longitude: ${ lng } | latitude: ${ lat }`);
  }
} else {
  /* geolocation IS NOT available  */
  console.log('geolocation IS NOT available on your browser');
}
```

Comment: `"geolocation" in navigator` and `navigator.geolocation` are fairly equivalent as far as boolean expressions go

Comment: @Phil totally agreed with you Sir, **Edited**, Thankz :)

Comment: i know what is the problem. I added Timeout for 5 sec. And after 5 sec it says: "Uncaught (in promise) no position access"

Comment: Ohh , but you didn't provide full code with timeout. Ok best of luck

Comment: Try it over HTTPS